# SQL Inner Query In Replace Statement

Tags: sql, replace, mariadb, heidisql

I would like to replace a certain part of a columns field with something else. The only issue is that what I've tried doesn't work. I'm using HeidiSQL

This is a overview of the database: 
[Database Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YBGZ.png)

What I would like to do is for **each** user_id with **field_id 523** I would like to replace *'centraal-zorgportaal.nl/afbeeldingen/'* with *'/profiles/(for each user id here)/'*.

So the end result example after running the query will look like this: 
*'/profiles/711/logo.gif'*, but then for each user with a diffrent logo.gif.

*Note: Can't post more than two links so removed the http etc. in front.*

This is the query I've tried and dind't work:

```
update wp_bp_xprofile_data 
   set value = replace( value,
                        'http://www.centraal-zorgportaal.nl/afbeeldingen/',
                        '/profiles/' + 
                        (select user_id 
                           from wp_bp_xprofile_data 
                          where user_id = @n := @n + 1 n) + 
                        '/') 
  where field_id = 523
```

*(Table name is: wp_bp_xprofile_data)*

This is the error message I received:
[Error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqqb.png)

Could anyone explain why this doesn't work, how to fix it and the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Pictures are not good for the error messages, if you can't just copy it then write it down.

Comment: use CONCAT(str1,str2,...) instead of  plus(+)

Comment: Is the "database overview" really a "sample of data in the table"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL/MariaDB, you cannot refer to the table being modified.  From your description, you seem to want something like this:

```
update wp_bp_xprofile_data
    set value = replace(value,
                        'http://www.centraal-zorgportaal.nl/afbeeldingen/', 
                        concat('/profiles/', user_id, '/')
                       )
    where field_id = 523;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like I wanted!                                                      Edit: You already answered my remaining question.